# cannot install R package using install_local on linux server

Tags: r, linux

I have been trying to install "ncdf4" package in R locally for more than two days now.  First I tried installing "ncdf4" package with package.install() but it did not work. Afterwards, I downloaded binary file of the package and tried installing it using install_local:

```
    > library("devtools")
    > install_local("/path to the package/",quiet=FALSE)
```

However, this generated following error:

```
   Installation failed: cannot open the connection
   Warning message:
    In read.dcf(path) :
    cannot open compressed file 
    '/<path_to_the package>/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'Not a directory'
```

I also could not install some other packages using install_local(). Can anyone help me out in troubleshooting this error?

Comment: I'm having the same error with RStudio Cloud as well.